# How to connect a YouTube account to another email address

Tags: youtube, account-management, google-account, login

I recently got a YouTube account from someone, but I would like to be able to login with the Google account that I already have and connect it to the former YouTube account.

How can I add my own Google account (Gmail address) as a "manager" of the YouTube account (which is connected to its own Gmail account)? Or, vice versa, how can I add the YouTube channel to my Gmail account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

At this time it's not possible to move Youtube product data but it's possible to have several managers for Youtube channels linked to Google+ pages.

## Add or remove managers of a channel

From [2] (go to the reference to have access to the the linked pages at the source)

> If a channel is linked to a Google+ page, then multiple people can
> manage the channel without sharing passwords. For someone to manage
> the YouTube channel, they must be listed as a manager of the linked
> page.
>
> 1. Only the owner of the Google+ page can add or remove managers. Sign into the page owner Google Account.
> 2. On YouTube, make sure you pick the right channel. Then go to the channel's account settings and click Add or remove managers.
> 3. To add a manager, enter the email address of whoever you want to be a manager. Click Invite. Once they accept the invitation, they’ll
>    then be able to access that channel from their own Google Account.
> 4. To remove a manager, find the manager you want to remove, and click the X by their name. They will no longer be able to access the
>    channel from their Google Account.
>
> Learn more about adding managers and removing managers on a Google+
> page.

## References

- [1] [Moving product data - Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/58582)
- [2] [Add or remove managers of a channel - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4628007?hl=en)

Comment: fwiw, this is now handled via brand accounts, which basically are Google+ pages without the Google+ part.

Comment: fwiw, this is now handled via brand accounts, which basically are Google+ pages without the Google+ part.